# React Test Suite failed due to unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

I have an issue with my code. I am using JEST & Enzyme to run test on my project.

ChildComponent:

```
// Shortened for simplicity
Object.assign(ReactTableDefaults.column, {
    style: {"textAlign": "left"},
    headerStyle: {
      "fontWeight": "600", 
      "fontSize": "0.9em",
      "backgroundColor": "#DDE7ED",
      "color": "#1D3557",
      "borderColor": "#1D3557",
      "textAlign": "left"
    }
});
```

ParentComponent:

```
// Shortened for simplicity
render() {
let ChildComponent;
if (!this.state.submittedSearch) {
  ChildComponent = (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <hr />
      <h3>Please ensure that you fill up all the fields.</h3>
    </div>
  );
} else {
  ChildComponent = (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <ChildComponent
          {...props} />
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
//Shortened for simplicity
```

● Test suite failed to run

```
E:\cv_UserTemp\*****\node_modules\react-table\react-table.css:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.ReactTable{position:relative;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}.ReactTable *{box-sizing:border-box}.ReactTable .rt-table{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex:auto 1;flex:auto 1;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-webkit-box-align:stretch;-ms-flex-align:stretch;align-items:stretch;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;overflow:auto}.ReactTable .rt-thead{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex:1 0 auto;flex:1 0 auto;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

  17 |       "fontWeight": "600",
  18 |       "fontSize": "0.9em",
> 19 |       "backgroundColor": "#DDE7ED",
  20 |       "color": "#1D3557",
  21 |       "borderColor": "#1D3557",
  22 |       "textAlign": "left"

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (I:/*****/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316:17)
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this error. At first I suspected it has something to do with my `webpack.config.js` or my `.babelrc`. But after tinkering around with my code, I am still not sure what is going on. Below is what my `.babelrc` looks like:

```
//.babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-flow",
    "babel-preset-latest",
    "babel-preset-env",
    "babel-preset-stage-2",
    "react",
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

I am using the following:

- React v15.6.2
- ReactDom v15.6.2
- babel-polyfill v6.23.0
- babel-jest v23.0.1
- babel-preset-env v1.4.0

Thank you for your help

Comment: what if you remove this style block? does error go away? block looks legal as for me

Comment: If i remove it all my styling will go and i need to find another means to style my layout again. I can experiment but i think the deeper root is something to do with the versions compatibility (just a hunch?). But even if there is no way to resolve this error i wanna know the root cause for learning :)

Comment: I propose you just find particular statement that causes an error. You will get it back later. Telling the truth, have never faced a case when "." became invalid(`if .` or `{a: .}` reproduce error message but surely is not your case)